# how can i use io.open to open a unicode path in lua

Tags: unicode, lua, io

here is my code:

```
local path = "C:/Users/KayWang/Desktop/测试.txt"
local file,err = io.open(path,"rb")
print(file,err)
```

and this is the output:

```
nil C:/Users/KayWang/Desktop/测试.txt: No such file or directory
```

I don't want to use winapi
and I really want to know why this function cann't support unicode path?

Comment: Lua standard library functions accept filenames only in OS-native codepage.  For Lua on Windows, you must manually convert filenames from UTF-8 to your Windows codepage (probably, yours is CP936) prior to invoking `io.open`.

Comment: thanks ! I convert filenames from UTF-8 to GBK,and it works!

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not possible.

E.g. my Windows system has default cp-1251 (Russian) so I can not represent your path in it. So to be able open this file I have to use unicode path.
But C api does not provide such functionality. But if your code page support your path then you can convert your unicode path to it and use it with `io.open`.
In other case you have to use some C code. I think easy way is just use MS extension like `_wfopen` wich uses UTF-16 as arguments. Other way is use `CreateFileW` and then wrap handle to file descriptor and this descriptor to file pointer.

Also you can use some external IO library which supports such path.
I just test my libuv binding and be able read/write file on my system.
(File path in utf-8)